# Heroku and socket.io out of memory

Tags: linux, heroku, websocket

I have a setup with websockets on heroku and every now and then i get a flurry of messages like this:

`06:24.591694+00:00 heroku router - - at=error code=H15 desc="Idle connection" method=GET path="/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=vi55QjrI6GIqRBkjAABw" host=www.weld.io request_id=2a9bf2f7-e84c-47e3-81e6-d445b32d0c5c fwd="<a lot of different IP.s>" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=95906ms status=503 bytes=140`

This goes on until the heroku instance run out of memory. This happens every other day or so and in between that everything works fine? Any idea what it could be?

Comment: Im experiencing the same. Could you ever solve this?

Comment: Sorry, I just stopped using socket.io. Never found a solution.

Comment: have you tried to enable xhr-polling on socket.io?